# How best to setup rails with only one view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canvas, view, routes, single-page-application

I'm working on a personal RoR project with an interesting sort of problem: the whole app only needs one HTML template.

Basically, the whole app is presented through HTML5 canvas (it's going to be a game of sorts). But I'd still like there to be URLs for accessing specific resources, such as '/player/1'.

So what's the best, DRYest way to do this? I'd really hate to specify the template in every action in the controllers.

Comment: It's a very broad question, but it all starts with your data organization. Organize your data, create your framework (controllers, default views) define your routes and modify the views as you want them...

Comment: Single Page Apps > Backbone JS, Angular JS, Node JS (for socket.io, for games/chat)

Comment: Yes, I plan to use Backbone.js, but how do I tell rails to render the same template for all actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render :file => "layout_file", :layout => false
```

Comment: How can this be applied in a DRY way to all actions?

Comment: this is untested, but possibly put that code in an after_filter (or after_action is your riding rails 4)

Answer (score 1):

You could define your view in `app/views/layout/application.html.erb` and leave all the others empty, but that wouldn't avoid the reloading of pages.
You should also have all your methods respond in json format.

Or just an old good:

```
render :nothing => true
```

at the end of your methods.

Comment: That throws a missing template exception for every route unless empty template files are defined for each actions.

Comment: of course you have to create the corresponding files, but you can leave them empty.

Comment: Seems like an ugly solution. Isn't there any way to avoid having repetitive empty files?